# How do I run Python through Apache Similar to PHP?

Tags: python, apache

I am trying to set up the latest version of Python through the latest version of Apache HTTP server and I am clueless as to what I should do next?

Comment: That's not very good setup from the ground up. Modern web-applications (including those written on Python) are deployed in quite different ways.

Comment: @ulidtko: And what these ways will be? Apache HTTP server is still one of the most popular servers for production environments.

Comment: Those who will claim that Apache is no good for modern web applications don't know how to set Apache up properly. For Python (mod_wsgi) the Apache defaults are very sub optimal and set up for static file serving and PHP, not for Python. So regardless of what the critics may say, Apache/mod_wsgi is still regarded as the leading choice for Python web deployment. Other options are uWSGI and gunicorn. What ever the solution, if you don't invest the time in setting it up right for your specific application, of course you will get poor results.

Answer (score 2):

One solution will be to use [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/). Another one is [modwsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

I recommend that you read the [chapter](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/) in the Django Book about deployment. Even if you aren't using Django, it will expose you to the technologies used by most python developers.

Comment: The mod_python project is no longer developed and will not compile from latest source code release on latest Apache.